# Can a website be only partially AMP compliant and still get the benefits of using AMP?

Tags: drupal, view, amp-html

My situation is that I'm working on a Drupal 8 website, and the module to allow for the site's output to be AMP compliant only works on content pages, not "views" pages. Essentially this means that a single article node can be made to be AMP compliant, but the front page of the website can't be.

If I build my site in this way, would google still be able to look at the AMP stuff from the content pages and ignore the front page, or would my whole website be disqualified for not having an AMP compliant front page?

I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question, I'm still wrapping my head around how this all works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this by linking pages with  for only amp pages you have done. Use following code in head section. For more information [**Click Here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)

**Non AMP Pages**

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/your-amp-content-page.html">
```

**AMP Pages**

```
<link rel="canonical" ref="https://www.example.com/your-non-amp-content-page.html">
```